# SwiftUI - Multiple Repetitions

Tags: swiftui, repeat

I need to display a specific text for the each day of the year, when I repeat the code around 30 times, everything is fine, if I extend the code for each day, 365 times, I get an error.

Code:

```
if ("\(formatDate(date: today))") .elementsEqual("01-01"){
                                Text("Lucy")
                            }
                    else if ("\(formatDate(date: today))") .elementsEqual("02-01"){
                                Text("Karl")
                            }
                    else if ("\(formatDate(date: today))") .elementsEqual("03-01"){
                                Text("Jack")
                            }
                    else if ("\(formatDate(date: today))") .elementsEqual("04-01"){
                                Text("Tim")
                            }
                    else if ("\(formatDate(date: today))") .elementsEqual("05-01"){
                                Text("Sarah")
                            }
// and so on ... 365x
```

Error:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Comment: Is there really no more efficient way to achieve the results that you're looking for than an `if/else` clause with 365 branches? Is the `Text` that you generate really 100% unique for each case, or is there a function that you can use to generate the `Text` based on the result you're looking for?

Comment: The Text is 100% unique Name for each day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to set up a `Dictionary<String,String>`, where the key is the formatted date and the value is the resulting text:

```
let dateTextDictionary = [
    "01-01":"Lucy",
    "02-01":"Karl",
    "03-01":"Tim",
]
```

```
if let resultText = dateTextDictionary[formatDate(date: today)] {
    Text(resultText)
}
```

This dictionary could also be loaded from a JSON file or plist.

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely happening is that your program is too inefficient.
If I am understand your question correctly, here's what I would do:

```
var texts = ["Lucy", "Karl", "Jack", "Tim", "Sarah"] //and so on with whatever texts you are using.
for x in 1...365 {
   if x < 10 {
      if ("\(formatDate(date: today))") .elementsEqual("0\(x)-01"){
                                Text("\(texts[x-1])")
                            }
   } else {
      if ("\(formatDate(date: today))") .elementsEqual("\(x)-01"){
                                Text("\(texts[x-1])")
                            }
   }

}
```

Comment: You're missing the `\()` interpolation marks in your `Text`s